# Bash script to check which serial port is connected

Tags: python, linux, bash, serial-port

I have a device I connect to with the serial port. I have a python program that talks to it. But this must be launched via a bash script, which will first check which serial port it is connected to, and provide necessary permission. Then it will launch the python script, which should have a mechanism to understand which port it is connected to (like an argument being passed to it by bash script).

Currently my bash script is

```
#script
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB1
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB2
```

If the device is connected to ttyUSB1, I get the error `chmod: cannot access ‘/dev/ttyUSB0’: No such file or directory` for the first line. That's how I know it's connected to USB1. The python program has the line `ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1',115200, timeout=1)` which I change manually once I know which is the correct serial port.

How do I check which port the device is connected to, and inform to the python program?

Answer (score 0):

Since your using chmod you can check for the exit code using $? and include an if statement to break out of the script and load the python.

As an example:

```
#!bash
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0
if [$? = 0]
   then 
    pythonscript /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Mileage may vary here, its pretty hacky. You may also want to just use

```
if [ -f /dev/ttyUSB0 ]
```

Assuming the file only exists when the device is attached. I don't have specific experience with that so I won't speculate on the long term viability of polling that as a file. I've run into problems with unattached devices and existing entries in /dev/ so keep an eye on this.

Refrences for further reading:

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Comment: I have tested `if [ -f /dev/ttyUSB0 ]` but it does not work with dev files

Answer (score 0):

You can parse `dmesg` output with AWK and pass the results to a Python script via argument.

For example, this command will pass the port names to script `print_argument.py`:

```
dmesg | awk '$0 ~ "attached to ttyUSB.+$" { dev[$NF] = 1 } $0 ~ "disconnected from ttyUSB.+$" { delete dev[$NF] } END { for(i in dev) print i }' | xargs python print_argument.py
```

So if your `dmesg` output looks like this:

```
[ 5847.898803] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 5847.898835] ftdi_sio 1-5.1:1.0: device disconnected
[ 5979.369955] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[ 5979.512177] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001
[ 5979.512184] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5979.512187] usb 1-1: Product: FT232R USB UART
[ 5979.512191] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: FTDI
[ 5979.512194] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: A901E5L7
[ 5979.514985] ftdi_sio 1-1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[ 5979.515064] usb 1-1: Detected FT232RL
[ 5979.515574] usb 1-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
```

And the `print_argument.py` contains:

```
import sys
print ('/dev/' + sys.argv[1])
```

Python script output from the command above would be:

```
/dev/ttyUSB1
```